# Method put of Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage for Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

What are the option of the method put of Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage fro Laravel 6

```
Storage::put($path, $contents [, $options])
```

Comment: @KurtFriars Frankly, I took a quick look in the code and I'm still somewhat unclear on what `$options` supports, and I've been working with Laravel for years. It appears in some cases things like `'visibility' => 'public'` can be passed for drivers like S3, but I really can't blame a newbie from having a hard time locating the list.

Comment: Yes, and in the other case it is for league/flystsem $config. @ceejayoz I concede the answer to this question is significantly obfuscated from examining the code. I will delete my prior comments and remove my downvote. Thanks for allowing OPs question to stand. Wont let me do it, since it was too long ago.

Comment: @KurtFriars Appreciate your hearing me out!

Comment: I just went in search of this same thing and found nothing, even in the FlySystem site. I wonder if anyone has thought to compile a list of options as they find them. Though I doubt it since it seems no one can find them anywhere. What is the point of an options parameter if no one wants to document how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a way to pass options to the underlying Filesystem driver, so the options vary from driver to driver.

In general, you won't need this much; the most common use case I can find is for telling the S3 driver to make a file public by passing `'public'` or `['visibility' => 'public']`. (It's likely you could also pass S3 headers here.)